How to create rule in elastic having filed with epoch time?
There is an index having documents with Name, cluster, Expiration fields. Expiration field having expiry date but on epoch format (1738138757) and I want to create rule in elastic to alert 30 days before the expiry date.
I have created a rule but don't know how to add the filter like expiration between now - now+30d but it's not working as this field is not type timestamp. Please let me know how to do that or any other alternative.

I don’t understand why you have the problem
Mapping with the only signicant expiration field
PUT /expiration_date_filter
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "expiration": {
                "type": "date"
            }
        }
    }
}

Documents with dates in the epoch format
PUT /expiration_date_filter/_bulk?refresh
{"index":{"_id":1}}
{"expiration":"1719738138757"}
{"index":{"_id":2}}
{"expiration":"1720738138757"}
{"index":{"_id":3}}
{"expiration":"1721738138757"}
{"index":{"_id":4}}
{"expiration":"1724738138757"}
{"index":{"_id":5}}
{"expiration":"1726738138757"}

Query to show dates
GET /expiration_date_filter/_search?filter_path=hits.hits.fields
{
    "fields": ["expiration"],
    "_source": false
}

Response
{
    "hits" : {
        "hits" : [
            {
                "fields" : {
                    "expiration" : [
                        "2024-06-30T09:02:18.757Z"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "fields" : {
                    "expiration" : [
                        "2024-07-11T22:48:58.757Z"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "fields" : {
                    "expiration" : [
                        "2024-07-23T12:35:38.757Z"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "fields" : {
                    "expiration" : [
                        "2024-08-27T05:55:38.757Z"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "fields" : {
                    "expiration" : [
                        "2024-09-19T09:28:58.757Z"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

Query with date filter on 2024/06/29
GET /expiration_date_filter/_search?filter_path=hits.hits.fields
{
    "query": {
        "range": {
            "expiration": {
                "gte": "now/d",
                "lte": "now+30d/d"
            }
        }
    },
    "fields": ["expiration"],
    "_source": false
}

Response
{
    "hits" : {
        "hits" : [
            {
                "fields" : {
                    "expiration" : [
                        "2024-06-30T09:02:18.757Z"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "fields" : {
                    "expiration" : [
                        "2024-07-11T22:48:58.757Z"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "fields" : {
                    "expiration" : [
                        "2024-07-23T12:35:38.757Z"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

